# Padding-left not working in QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, padding, qtstylesheets

I've created `QListWidget`:

```
QListWidget *list = new QListWidget();
list->addItem("Item 1");
list->addItem("Item 2");
list->addItem("Item 3");
```

Then i've applied my stylesheet:

```
QListWidget::item {
    padding: 5px;
}

QListWidget::item:selected {
    background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #369, stop:1 #147);
    color: white;
}
```

But `padding` not working in the left side. So i have that:

[image]

So, can i create left padding on QSS, not on C++?
P.S. I tried to write `padding-left: 5px`, it is not working too.
P.P.S. In `QListWidget::item:selected` that padding is working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
/* Works for both QListView and QListWidget */
QListView::item {
    /* Won't work without borders set */
    border: 0px;

    padding-left: 10px;
}

/* For icon only */
QListView::icon {
    left: 10px;
}

/* For text only */
QListView::text {
    left: 10px;
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have an answer to the question *why doesn't it work without borders set* but ... it works when you do set them.

Comment: Works only when hovered.

Comment: Be warned of a long-standing bug in Qt. As soon as you add a border property, you may get new trouble. A border comes with a color, even if you don't explicitely specify the border color. And as soon as there is a color set by the style sheet, colors set by your model's data() function will be ignored. - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122698